# How to scroll through all columns

Tags: jquery

Here is an issue that I am facing with jQuery (see [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tlsatyam/a0m4fuwx/18/)):

```
jQuery("#column_01").on("scroll", function () {

var scrolledleft = parseInt(jQuery("#column_01").scrollTop()) * -1;

var scrolledleft1= parseInt(jQuery("#column_01").scrollTop()) * 1;
  //console.log(scrolledleft1);
    jQuery("#column_03").scrollTop(scrolledleft1 + scrolledright);
    
    
    //for center
    jQuery("#column_02").scrollTop(scrolledleft + scrolledcenter);
})


//Move center column to bottom initially
var oh = jQuery("#column_02  .right_container").outerHeight(true);
var oh1 = jQuery("#column_02").outerHeight(true);
//alert(oh);
//alert(oh1);

jQuery("#column_02").scrollTop(jQuery("#column_02 .right_container").height());
//Get actual distance scrolled
var scrolledright = parseInt(jQuery("#column_03").scrollTop());
//console.log(scrolledright);

var scrolledcenter = parseInt(jQuery("#column_02").scrollTop());
```

**First Column:**

1. when user Scroll down first column, It up second column and down third column that is perfect (working fine)
2. As user scroll UP, then second column come down and third column come up (working fine)

The issue is that I want the same thing for second and third column then it stuck.

**Second column:**

1. As user scrolls down, then the first column up and the third column scrolls up.
2. If a user scrolls up, then the first column scrolls down and the third column scrolls down.

**Third column:**

1. As user scrolls down, then the first column scrolls down and the second column scrolls up.
2. As user scrolls up, then the first column scrolls up and the second column scrolls down

How can I achieve that?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean?

Comment: Have you checked the link i mention above ?if you will see the link  when i scroll second column it not effect first and third column.what Exactly i need for second column i mention above

Comment: Second column:

1.) As user scrolls down, then the first column up and the third column scrolls up.

2.) If a user scrolls up, then the first column scrolls down and the third column scrolls down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put this code into your script

EDIT::

```
 var scrollColumn1 = true;
var scrollColumn2 = false;
var scrollColumn3 = false;

    jQuery("#column_01").on("scroll", function () {

        if(scrollColumn1) {

            scrollColumn2 = false;
            scrollColumn3 = false;
           var scrolledleft = parseInt(jQuery("#column_01").scrollTop()) * -1;

var scrolledleft1= parseInt(jQuery("#column_01").scrollTop()) * 1;
    jQuery("#column_03").scrollTop(scrolledleft1 + scrolledright);

    jQuery("#column_02").scrollTop(scrolledleft + scrolledcenter);
        } else
            scrollColumn1 = true;
    });

   jQuery("#column_02").scrollTop(jQuery("#column_02 .right_container").height());


var scrolledright = parseInt(jQuery("#column_03").scrollTop());

var scrolledcenter = parseInt(jQuery("#column_02").scrollTop());


    jQuery("#column_02").on("scroll", function () {

        if(scrollColumn2) {

            scrollColumn1 = false;
            scrollColumn3 = false;
           var scrolledleft = parseInt(jQuery("#column_02").scrollTop()) * 1;

        var scrolledleft1= parseInt(jQuery("#column_02").scrollTop()) * 1;

            jQuery("#column_03").scrollTop(scrolledleft1 + scrolledright1);

            jQuery("#column_01").scrollTop(scrolledleft + scrolledcenter1);
        } else 
            scrollColumn2 = true;
    });

    var scrolledright1 = parseInt(jQuery("#column_01").scrollTop());

    var scrolledcenter1 = parseInt(jQuery("#column_03").scrollTop());

    jQuery("#column_03").on("scroll", function () {


        if(scrollColumn3) {
            scrollColumn2 = false;
            scrollColumn1 = false;
           var scrolledleft = parseInt(jQuery("#column_03").scrollTop()) * -1;

        var scrolledleft1= parseInt(jQuery("#column_03").scrollTop()) * 1;
          jQuery("#column_01").scrollTop(scrolledleft1 + scrolledcenter2);

          jQuery("#column_02").scrollTop(scrolledleft + scrolledright2);
        } else 
            scrollColumn3 = true;
    });


    jQuery("#column_01").scrollTop(jQuery("#column_01 .right_container").height());

    var scrolledright2 = parseInt(jQuery("#column_02").scrollTop());

    var scrolledcenter2 = parseInt(jQuery("#column_01").scrollTop());
```

Comment: I have implemented code here http://jsfiddle.net/tlsatyam/a0m4fuwx/30/  .By default as page load only second scroll should be bottom but in the running example third and second both set to bottom in start

Comment: I mean as page load scroll like this UP | DOWN | UP .Right now it showing me UP | DOWN | DOWN . i really thanks to you please help me a bit more

Comment: Please add editable script.. I think now it's perfect. It's working?

Comment: I have added that script but not working according to me   http://jsfiddle.net/tlsatyam/a0m4fuwx/30   check here then you will see

Comment: I have again updated code now as page load postion of scroll fine as i want UP | DOWN | UP  but again same thiing as i scroll second column it should work like DOWN | UP |DOWN  .Right now its working like as i scroll second it third column scroll down then it start moving to top .It simple work like down|up|down as i scroll second column to top .http://jsfiddle.net/tlsatyam/a0m4fuwx/32/   see this link tehn you will get what i am saying

Comment: I think it's working as your requirement, but i don't understand your last comment..

Comment: Open this link http://jsfiddle.net/tlsatyam/a0m4fuwx/32/   as page load  see how it work  when user scroll up second column ? It should work like this  2.) If a user scrolls second column  up, then the first column scrolls down and the third column scrolls down.

Comment: so you want when second column scroll up at that time first column scroll down and third column scroll down??

Comment: Please check http://jsfiddle.net/a0m4fuwx/33/ now it's working as your requirement... :)

Comment: Hey are you jquery expert ?

Comment: If it is helpful to you than please accept my answer.

Comment: No .Thanks to you you really sort out my problem

Comment: actually small thing wanna ask after that i checked today and id ?

Comment: what are you talking about id??

Comment: Ok  i will ask here i was asking for gmail id but as you here i can discuss with you here

Comment: are you familiar with pure css3 ?

Comment: No. i have little bit know css3.

Answer (score 1):

Try this my code or please visit my code in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wahyukodar/tnd8jfd8/)

```js
 heightC1 = $('#column_01')[0].scrollHeight;
    heightC2 = $('#column_02')[0].scrollHeight;
    heightC3 = $('#column_03')[0].scrollHeight;

    $("#column_01").scrollTop(heightC1);
    heightC1 = $("#column_01").scrollTop();
    $("#column_01").scrollTop(0);

    $("#column_02").scrollTop(heightC2);
    heightC2 = $("#column_02").scrollTop();
    $("#column_02").scrollTop(0);

    $("#column_03").scrollTop(heightC3);
    heightC3 = $("#column_03").scrollTop();
    $("#column_03").scrollTop(0);

$("#column_01").on("scroll", function () {
    var scrollVal = $("#column_01").scrollTop();
      console.log("Value scroll: "+scrollVal);
    var percentage = 100 * scrollVal / heightC1;
      console.log("Percentage: "+percentage);
    var diff2 = heightC2 - (heightC2 * percentage/ 100) ; 
      console.log("Diff2: "+diff2);
    var valScroll = heightC2-diff2; 
      console.log("Valscroll: "+valScroll);
    $("#column_02").scrollTop(valScroll);
    var diff3 = heightC3 - (heightC3 * percentage/ 100) ; 
      console.log("Diff3: "+diff3);
    var valScroll2 = heightC3-diff3;
    console.log("Valscroll: "+valScroll2);
    $("#column_03").scrollTop(valScroll2);
});
```

```css
#column_01 {
   background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #eeeeee;
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 2%;
    width: 29%;
    overflow-x:hidden;
 }
#column_02 {
     background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #eeeeee;
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0.5%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 2%;
    width: 29%;
    overflow-x:hidden;
   
}
#column_03 {
    width: 30%;
   float:left;
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: fixed;
    overflow:auto;
overflow-x:hidden;
}
#column_01, #column_02, #column_03{
    height:300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="column_01">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitationullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidat dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidat non proident, sunt in culpa dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur s dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incid qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incid magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation
ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidat dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidat non proident, sunt in culpa dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur s dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incid qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incid magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</div>
    <div id="column_02">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitationullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidat dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidat non proident, sunt in culpa dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur s dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occ</div>

<div id="column_03">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitationullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptat</div>
```